# How to get EBS gp3 IOPS & Througput pricing using api?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I can only seem to get the volume price per GB through the pricing api provided by AWS.

In the  AWS service index file for EC2, I can see only the volume pricing and IOPS but there is no pricing information regarding throughput.

Tried using the boto3 pricing client and adding filters for volumeType and volumeApiName.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just removing the volumeType filters and only using volumeApiName will give you all the information needed for pricing of the specific ebs volume type.